# How to suppress stdout and stderr output for openssl command?

Tags: powershell, openssl, libressl

Is it possible to disable the `stdout` and `stderr` output for the following command?

```
req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ./private.key -out ./mycert.crt -subj "/C=DE/ST=BW/L=Karlsruhe/O=foobar/OU=foobar/CN=foobar"
```

The command always produces the following output which I would like to suppress:

```
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
.............................................
.............................................................+++
........................................+++
writing new private key to './private.key'
```

I already tried to redirect the output with any variants of `2>&1` but his doesn't work in this scenario because of these reasons:

The `openssl` command is executed within a powershell session like this:

```
$opensslCommand = 'req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ./private.key -out ./mycert.crt -subj "/C=DE/ST=BW/L=Karlsruhe/O=foobar/OU=foobar/CN=foobar"'
Invoke-Expression -Command $opensslCommand
```

Again, the redirection of the PowerShell streams doesn't work either.
This wouldn't be a problem at all, but if your run the command in a non interactive mode the openssl output will be send to `stderr` and not to `stdout`.

`Git` behaves similar. But there you can change the output with these environment var: `$env:GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR = '2>&1'`

### Workaround

- Callstack:

> `Module Function` -- *calls* --> `Sub Function` -- *Invoke-Expression* --> `OpenSSL Command (with redirect *>$null)`

- Problem:

The error occurs because the *Sub Function* ist called with the `ErrorAction 'Stop'`. If I change it to the default `Continue` the output is suppressed.

To be still able to do a proper error handling I keep the global default `Error Action: Stop` and manually for the `Invoke-Command`:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
Invoke-Expression -Command 'openssl ... *>$null'
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
```

Comment: See `Get-Help about_redirection` or [read onlne](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6) redirect all streams and pipe to out-null `*>&1 | Out-Null`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've already tried this. But now I notice a weird behavior. The redirect works with `Invoke-Expression -Command "openssl .... 2>&1"` but not in this my module function :(

Answer (score 1):

Remember to also supress the `stdout` after merging `stderr` into it. If it doesn't work, wrap it in a scriptblock and redirect output from the entire thing, like so:

```
& { .\path\to\openssl.exe $opensslCommand.Split(' ') } 2>&1 1>$null
```